# Popup error displays control characters when opening Studio or Module Builder in Sugar

Tags: sugarcrm

In SugarCRM version 6.5.13, everything is working fine but when I open Studio, the dropdown editor, or Module Builder from admin panel, it shows an error. Something like the following section of control characters such as newline and tabs:

> \n\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

Here's a screenshot of the popup with the error:

[image: sugar error popup]

I am unable to trace issue.

Answer (score 0):

This points toward a corrupted cache. You'll need to clear either the browser or Sugar itself to get it back to normal.

1. Log out of Sugar
2. Clear browser cache (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
3. Close browser
4. Open up browser
5. Log back into Sugar

If that doesn't work, you'll need to clear the Sugar cache and try the steps again.

To clear the Sugar cache, delete all the contents of the **cache** directory.